# Vertically middle align text in a bootstrap column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need tree cells in tree columns(col-4), with an image, that determines the height of the cell, and vertically middle-aligned text, like this: 
[image]

This is what I get (**CodePen** [Here](http://codepen.io/serhio/pen/ZemNLe)):

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<style>   a{display:block;}   </style>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="background:red">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/75">
      <a style="background: yellow">Some text red-yellow</a>        
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="background:lightgreen">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/75">
      <a style="background: gray">some other text long text some other long text lightgreen-gray</a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="background:skyblue">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/75">
      <a style="background: violet">this is another long long long text that should be here skyblue-violet</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Use display: table; for parent class and display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; for child elements. This will give you vertical align correctly.

```html
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        a {
            display: block;
        }
        .customclass {
            display: table;
        }
        .customclass img, .customclass a{
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center customclass" style="background:red">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/75">
            <a style="background: yellow">Some text red-yellow</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center customclass" style="background:lightgreen">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/75">
            <a style="background: gray">some other text long text some other long text lightgreen-gray</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center customclass" style="background:skyblue">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/75">
            <a style="background: violet">this is another long long long text that should be here skyblue-violet</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to set the max-height after the image (unknown) height and cut the exceeding of the text?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are closing the first `<a>` with a `</div>` tag mate, so you close the div with the row class too early. =)

Comment: yeah I fixed that as well in my answer but that wasn't the issue.

Comment: thanks. That improved the rendering, but not solved the problem ;)

Comment: @Serge found your issue, look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add following css code  :

```
img {vertical-align: middle;}
```

It align your `a` tag in the middle of image.

Comment: thanks, is not the image I need to align, but the text on the right of the image...